# To use RInterface.GetArrayToVBA inside VBA function with arrays

Tags: r, excel, rexcel, vba

Let an Excel spreadsheet to be connected to R through [**RExcel**](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html) and you want to write a VBA function which calls some R functions.

In your Excel spreadsheet you have a couple of simple arrays like the following ones:

[image]

The code could be something like this:

```
Function foo(x As Range, y As Range) As Variant

    RInterface.StartRServer

    If IsNumeric(x) = True Then
        RInterface.PutArrayFromVBA "x", x
    End If

    If IsNumeric(y) = True Then
        RInterface.PutArrayFromVBA "y", y
    End If

    foo = RInterface.GetArrayToVBA("cbind(x, y, y ^ x)")

End Function
```

and its evident purpose is to return a matrix containing `cbind(x, y, y ^ x)` in Excel.

I'm not able to get it, I get strange results as I slightly amend the code: sometimes output is equal to `1`, sometimes it's equal to `#VALUE!`... it doesn't work, though, and I am not able to understand the syntax needed in such a case.

Comment: Not sure how `R` works but isn't `GetArrayToVBA("cbind(x, y, y ^ x)")` supposed to be `GetArrayToVBA(cbind(x, y, y ^ x))` considering the fact that anything within quotes is considered as a string?

Comment: `Compile error: Sub or Function not defined`

...and it highlights `y`

Comment: What is the syntax/parametrers for `Rinterface.GetArray()`? Just did a quick search on internet. It is something like `Rinterface.GetArray("something", Range)`?

Comment: Unfortunately this is where my knowledge about `R` shows :p

Comment: **GetArrayToVBA** (_RExpression As String_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function foo(x As Range, y As Range) As Variant

RInterface.StartRServer
RInterface.PutArrayFromVBA "x", x.Value 'you were missing this .Value'
RInterface.PutArrayFromVBA "y", y.Value
foo = RInterface.GetArrayToVBA("cbind(x, y, y ^ x)")

End Function
```

I'm omitting your error checks since they will only cause other errors. If you want to do error checking do a on error goto

Comment: why was this answer unaccepted after it was accepted? is there anything that you'd like me to explain/add?